# Customizing Google Maps information bubble

Tags: google-maps

How would I customize the Google Maps information bubble when a user clicks on the red pin? For instance, I want add an input text field and a submit button within the bubble.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put HTML into the infowindow

Here's google's examples

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple-max.html