# Appending HTML to an element not loaded initially

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am using a google map on my website.

Now when displaying the map on the website, there are different Pins(locations) you can click on.

Once you click on a location, it displays a popup box(google maps bubble). Now I would like to d additional content next to the **Address**, field, and the only way I can do it is with jQuery.

Here is the html of the popup bubble:

```
<div class="google-map-placeholder">
 <div class="bubble-content">
   <h4>Address: </h4>
   <p class="custom-bubble-text">Lat and long...</p>
   <p class="custom-bubble-text">PE Offices</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

How I want to add my custom text custom to the Address: element

jQuery:

```
var x = $('div.google-map-placeholder').find('div.bubble-content p.custom-bubble-text').html();
            if(x == 'NY Offices'){
                $('div.google-map-placeholder').find('div.bubble-content h4').html('Address: My custom address');
            }
```

but it does not work (does not append my html)...

I guess I need to add an event listener when clicking on the Map Marker Icon, but how do i do that?

[image: google maps image]

Comment: You should add a google maps event listener: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to go is a custom info box plugin from google maps called infobox.js

See the following links:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/docs/examples.html
[Customizing Google Maps information bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330303/customizing-google-maps-information-bubble)

Hope this helps

Comment: yeah I guess this is the best way to go about editing google maps.thank you

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Will let you add an event listener to a DOM node represented by a jQuery object.

```
$("#target").click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

I feel like you MAY run into issues with the dom that you're targeting (inside of the popup) to modify inside of the onClick handler not being ready for you when the onClick even is fired.